# Can't disable idle screen blanking in GNOME 3.22

Tags: fedora, x11, gnome, gnome3

I'm using Fedora 25 and my screen always blanks after 10 minutes of inactivity. I tried disabling it since it's very annoying when watching videos, but I didn't have any luck so far. These are the steps i tried, but none of them worked:

- Disabled screen blanking in Settings->Power
- Disabled X screen blanking with

  ```
  xset -dpms
  xset s off
  xset dpms 0 0 0 && xset s noblank && xset s off
  ```
- Tried running GNOME under Wayland
- Tried setting the following gsettings

  - org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.idle-activation-enabled to false
  - org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.lock-delay to 0
  - org.gnome.desktop.session.idle-delay to 0 and 10800
  - org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.sleep-display-ac to 0
  - org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.sleep-display-battery to 0
  - org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.idle-dim to false

Nothing worked, my screen still goes blank after 10 minutes. Any settings I could have overlooked?

Comment: Did you turn screen lock off in privacy settings? It might be interfering. Else you could get the `caffeine` extension and use that.

Comment: Sounds almost like a visual bell, is it possible to have that in a graphical environment?

Comment: Neither turning off screen lock nor caffeine made any difference :/

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, XFCE installed xscreensaver as a dependency and it was automatically started alongside GNOME for some reason